# Grako's ordered match

Tags: python, grako

```
@@grammar::tester
@@comments :: /\(\*((?:.|\n)*?)\*\)/
@@eol_comments :: /(#([^\n]*?)$|\/\/([^\n]*?)$)/

start = pattern $;
pattern =
    | number
    | anything
    ;
anything = ?'\S*';
number = ?"-?(0|[1-9]*[0-9]*)(\.[0-9]+)?([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?";
```

This does parse an input files of

```
xxx
```

This gives error

```
grako.exceptions.FailedParse: learn.txt(1:1) Expecting end of text. :
```

xxx

To my understanding, the pattern rule would try to match 'number', which it cann't. Then it should proceed to try to match anything and successful.

Why doesn't this parse?

Comment: I figured out why. The reason is that number pattern can match empty string, which would consider '' a match for 'number' a success, then try to match $, which failed. change to
number = ?"-?(0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)(\.[0-9]+)?([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?";

fixed it.

Comment: Your analysis is correct. The pattern for `anything` is probably broken too.